# react-native appstate not updating after camera is closed

Tags: android, react-native

my react-native app shows a modal(`react-native-modal`) from main screen. This modal has a button to launch camera (`react-native-image-picker`).

After a photo is taken the modal should re-appear.
But the problem is, modal is not showing up.
Instead the main screen from which modal was launched is shown.
Only after i minimize the app and then bring it to foreground the modal is shown!

I found that,
when modal is shown, `appState` is `active` in the modal,
and when camera is shown `appState` is `background` in the modal.
But after camera is closed `appState` remains `background` in the modal!
and in the main screen `appState` is `active`

i tried setting `visibility` of the modal inside mainscreen again after photo is taken, but still modal is not showing.. only after i minimize the app and bring it to foreground again, the modal is being shown!

How can i notify my main screen that, camera module is completed/unmounted and currently the appstate is active, not background? (issue occurs in android only)

Is it something related to the way activity work and related to `android:launchMode`?
I tried singleTop instead of singleTask, but still no luck.
Can somebody please let me know how to tell my app that, after camera picture is taken, the app is not in background anymore and the camera activity is completed?

this is the current activity part of my `androidmanifest.xml` file

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

in my main screen code i am using my ModalComponent `MyModal`  using a `visibility` state variable

```
render() {
    {this.state.visibility && (
       <MyModal visibility={this.state.visibility} />
    )}

}
```

and inside my `MyModal` component

```
render() {
        {this.props.visibility && (
        <MyModal
                    isVisible={this.props.visibility}
                    avoidKeyboard
        > )}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

class MyModalComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visibility: true,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    }

    _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        if (nextAppState === 'active') {
            this.setState({ visibility: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ visibility: false });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <MyModal
                isVisible={this.state.visibility}
                avoidKeyboard
            />
        );
    }
}
```

- The issue you're facing is due to the way Android handles activity lifecycles. When you open the camera, it creates a new activity on top of your app. When you close the camera, it finishes the activity and returns to your app. However, the state of your app is still the same as it was before opening the camera. This is why you need to manually set the state of your app to active.
- React-Native AppState : https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: I have tried this, but not solving the problem. Thanks anyway